# Writing text on a WriteableBitmap

Tags: wpf, writeablebitmap

I have searched around and found that most of the answers convert a `WriteableBitmap` to a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`. I am currently thinking of using `WriteableBitmapEx`'s `Blitz()` function to overlay a bitmap with text onto the existing bitmap, but I don't really find functions that return `WriteableBitmap`.

Is there a easy way to draw text?

Comment: Did you consider placing a TextBlock on top of an Image and then render their parent Panel into a RenderTargetBitmap?

Comment: @Clemens Nope. Do you have a simple example for me to start from?

Comment: Search Stack Overflow. There are plenty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to use the WriteableBitmapEx `DrawString()` method to achieve this directly.

Unfortunately it is not inside the Nuget Packages so it has to be compiled from the source of another project:

https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/discussions/579148

https://fastwpfgrid.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WriteableBitmapEx/LetterGlyphTool.cs